# plotting cumulative density plot using fitdistrplus object without a histogram

Tags: r, plot, fitdistrplus

The R package [fitdistrplus](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/fitdistrplus.pdf) has a `denscomp` function that plots the fitted cumulative density curve along with a histogram of the data. As an R newbie, I appreciate all the plots available in this package.

Is there a simple way to just plot the curve without the histogram?

I couldn't find an option like `histogram = FALSE` in the `denscomp` function in the documentation.

How should I use the `fitdist$estimate` to plot just the cumulative density curve?

Comment: an explanation for the downvote would be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's an easy way to change the behavior of `denscomp`, but you can roll your own density plot using the distribution parameters returned by `fitdist`. Here's an example:

Set up to plot three plots in a single window:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1), mar=c(4,4,3,1))
library(fitdistrplus)
```

Create a `fitdist` object using an example adpated from the help for `denscomp`:

```
data(groundbeef)
serving <- groundbeef$serving
fitW <- fitdist(serving, "weibull")
```

Now let's make a standard `denscomp` plot:

```
denscomp(fitW, plotstyle="graphics", main="denscomp Version")
```

Now we'll roll our own Weibull density using the parameters returned by `fitdist`. `fitW$estimate` contains the `shape` and `scale` parameters of the fitted Weibull distribution for the `serving` data. Below we generate the same plot as above using these parameters:

```
x=seq(0, max(serving), length=100)
serving_dwei = dweibull(x, shape=fitW$estimate["shape"], scale=fitW$estimate["scale"])

hist(serving, freq=FALSE, main="Roll Your Own")
lines(x=x, y=serving_dwei, col="red")
```

And finally, the density plot alone:

```
plot(x=x, y=serving_dwei, type="l", main="Density alone", xlab="Serving", ylab="Density")
```

All three plots are shown below:

[image]

If you want to compare the Weibull fit with the empirical kernel density, you can do this:

```
plot(x=x, y=serving_dwei, type="l", main="Weibull fit plus empirical density", 
     xlab="Serving", ylab="Density", 
     ylim=c(0,max(c(serving_dwei, density(serving)$y))))
lines(density(serving), col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU for a thorough, clear answer. The missing link for me was the use of density function (dweibull).